# MS Access SQL Error on Clause

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to run this query down below and i keep getting an error.  The query runs perfectly fine in SQL Server but I don't know why I'm getting the error.

```
Select *
FROM    Products_Products
Join
(SELECT Products_Prices_ProductID, 
    Max(IIf(Products_Prices_Code='ONEK',Products_Prices_Price,Null)) AS ONEK, 
    Max(IIf(Products_Prices_Code='FIVEK',Products_Prices_Price,Null)) AS FIVEK, 
    Max(IIf(Products_Prices_Code='TENK',Products_Prices_Price,Null)) AS TENK, 
    Max(IIf(Products_Prices_Code='TWENTYFIVEK',Products_Prices_Price,Null)) AS  TWENTYFIVEK,
    Max(IIf(Products_Prices_Code='Fifty',Products_Prices_Price,Null)) AS Fifty, 
    Max(IIf(Products_Prices_Code='OneHundred',Products_Prices_Price,Null)) AS OneHundred, 
    Max(IIf(Products_Prices_Code='FiveHundred',Products_Prices_Price,Null)) AS FiveHundred
FROM Products_Prices
GROUP BY Products_Prices_ProductID
) As pp
ON Products_Products_ID = pp_ProductID
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is the full error? Provide any other relevant information you have.

Comment: Syntax Error in FROM clause.

Comment: Access SQL does not support an unqualified `Join` keyword. Try using `INNER JOIN` instead.

Comment: I don't believe you that this runs as written in SQL Server.  Neither field that you are joining on, `Products_Products_ID` nor `pp_ProductID`, is included in your subquery.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but try this

```
Select *
FROM    Products_Products
Join
(SELECT Products_Prices_ProductID AS pp_ProductID, 
    Max(IIf(Products_Prices_Code='ONEK',Products_Prices_Price,Null)) AS ONEK, 
    Max(IIf(Products_Prices_Code='FIVEK',Products_Prices_Price,Null)) AS FIVEK, 
    Max(IIf(Products_Prices_Code='TENK',Products_Prices_Price,Null)) AS TENK, 
    Max(IIf(Products_Prices_Code='TWENTYFIVEK',Products_Prices_Price,Null)) AS  TWENTYFIVEK,
    Max(IIf(Products_Prices_Code='Fifty',Products_Prices_Price,Null)) AS Fifty, 
    Max(IIf(Products_Prices_Code='OneHundred',Products_Prices_Price,Null)) AS OneHundred, 
    Max(IIf(Products_Prices_Code='FiveHundred',Products_Prices_Price,Null)) AS FiveHundred
FROM Products_Prices
GROUP BY Products_Prices_ProductID
) As pp
ON Products_Products_ID = pp_ProductID
```

Just added an alias to the field `Products_Products_ID` of inner table as `pp_ProductID`. Hopefully, this resolves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Changes I made:

- Changed `Join` to `INNER JOIN`
- Explicitly included all fields from both tables
- Added alias to table Products_Products.
- Fixed names of fields you are joining on.

---

```
Select P.*, PP.*
FROM    Products_Products AS P
INNER JOIN
(SELECT Products_Prices_ProductID, 
    Max(IIf(Products_Prices_Code='ONEK',Products_Prices_Price,Null)) AS ONEK, 
    Max(IIf(Products_Prices_Code='FIVEK',Products_Prices_Price,Null)) AS FIVEK, 
    Max(IIf(Products_Prices_Code='TENK',Products_Prices_Price,Null)) AS TENK, 
    Max(IIf(Products_Prices_Code='TWENTYFIVEK',Products_Prices_Price,Null)) AS  TWENTYFIVEK,
    Max(IIf(Products_Prices_Code='Fifty',Products_Prices_Price,Null)) AS Fifty, 
    Max(IIf(Products_Prices_Code='OneHundred',Products_Prices_Price,Null)) AS OneHundred, 
    Max(IIf(Products_Prices_Code='FiveHundred',Products_Prices_Price,Null)) AS FiveHundred
FROM Products_Prices
GROUP BY Products_Prices_ProductID
) As pp
ON P.Products_Products_ID = pp.Products_Prices_ProductID
```